# Producing bigger pages with a font editor for Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I use Hiero, java version, because I want to create fonts for CCLabelBMFont.

However, due to my game being on retina display, my font images are big, and they require more than one page. Cocos2d only supports one.

So, essentially, how can I produce bigger pages (canvases)? I don't think Hiero has that feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on `Glyph cache` radio button. Then adjust `Page width` and `Page height` until it says `Pages: 1`. Then change the font size to the size you want. Re-adjust page width/height if the new font size increases the number of pages.

[image: Hiero]

p/s: Make sure you adjust page width/height before increasing the size. Hiero will freak out if you suddenly change to a large size without changing the page width/height, and stop displaying the sample rendering. If that happens, you have to close and restart Hiero.